# Not able to see ViewModel property in View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm still trying to get my head wrapped around using ViewModels and IEnumerable/List as properties. I'm obviously missing something that is not allowing me to see my IEnumerable in my View.

What I'm ultimately trying to do is have a view that will show a list of unassigned users not assigned to a Group (called Patrols in this case and would have PatrolId=0). The table will have a checkbox next to each member. Above that table will be a DropDownList of the available Patrols. The Admin will come to the page to see those that aren't assigned, select a Patrol from the DDL at the top, check the users he want's to assign to that Patrol, and then submit the form that will pass the PatrolID from the DDL and find all the selected members in order to update their record with that PatrolId.

In the View below when I go to loop through the Scout property, I would assume I would be able to use Model.Scout in this part in order to loop through and write out all the members in that IEnumerable.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
```

However, when I try to use intellisense to see the Scout property when using the Model, I don't see the property. In addition to that I would think I would need to first check the Scout property to see if there is a count before I write out all the rows. Again, I can't see the Scout property in order to check it's count.

ViewModel

```
public class PatrolMemberViewModel
{
        [Key]
        public int MemberId { get; set; }

        public int PatrolId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Phone")]
        public string PhonePrimary { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string EmailPrimary { get; set; }

        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class PatrolUnassignedViewModel
{
        public SelectList Patrols { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<PatrolMemberViewModel> Scout { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
// GET: 
public ViewResult Unassigned()
{
    PatrolUnassignedViewModel unassinged = new PatrolUnassignedViewModel();
    unassinged.Patrols = new SelectList(repository.SelectAllPatrols());
    unassinged.Scout = repository.SelectAllUnassigned();
            
    return View(unassinged);
}
```

Repository

```
public IEnumerable<PatrolMemberViewModel> SelectAllUnassigned()
{
            using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
            {
                var results = (from p in db.Person
                               where p.IsActive == true
                               && p.IsScout == true
                               && p.PatrolId == 0
                               select new PatrolMemberViewModel
                               {
                                   MemberId = p.PID,
                                   FirstName = p.FirstName ?? string.Empty,
                                   LastName = p.LastName ?? string.Empty,
                                   EmailPrimary = p.EmailPrimary ?? string.Empty,
                                   PhonePrimary = p.PhonePrimary ?? string.Empty,
                                   PatrolId = p.PatrolId,
                                   IsSelected = false
                               }
                                ).OrderBy(o => o.LastName).ThenBy(o => o.FirstName).ToList();

                return results;
            }
}

public IEnumerable<PatrolName> SelectAllPatrols()
{
    return db.PatrolNames;
}
```

View

```
@model IList<ProjectName.ViewModels.PatrolUnassignedViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Unassigned";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Patrols</h2>
<h4>Assign Scouts to a Patrol.</h4>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Patrol", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "alert alert-danger" })

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed tbackground">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">

            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                First Name
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Last Name
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Email
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Phone
            </th>
        </tr>
    
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="mailto:@Model[i].EmailPrimary">@Model[i].EmailPrimary</a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].PhonePrimary)
            </td>
        </tr>
        }

    </table>
    
    <div class="control-wrapper">
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Assign Scouts" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
}
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You controller is returning a single instance of class PatrolUnassignedViewModel

```
    public ViewResult Unassigned()
    {
        PatrolUnassignedViewModel unassinged = new PatrolUnassignedViewModel();
        unassinged.Patrols = new SelectList(repository.SelectAllPatrols());
        unassinged.Scout = repository.SelectAllUnassigned();
        return View(unassinged);
    }
```

Your view is expecting an IList

```
@model IList<ProjectName.ViewModels.PatrolUnassignedViewModel>
```

When it should be expecting

```
@model ProjectName.ViewModels.PatrolUnassignedViewModel
```

Your scout is an IEnumerable so doesn't have a count method so should be

```
public IList<PatrolMemberViewModel> Scout { get; set; }
public IList<PatrolMemberViewModel> SelectAllUnassigned()
{
}
```

You should be doing your loop like this

```
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Scout.Count(); i++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Scout[i].IsSelected)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Scout[i].FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Scout[i].LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="mailto:@Model.Scout[i].EmailPrimary">@Model.Scout[i].EmailPrimary</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Scout[i].PhonePrimary)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Thank you! You and Shyju fixed me up but this response was the closest answer for me. IEnumberable does have count but I sill had to use IList because of the way I am looping through the Model in order to assign the checkboxes. Once I changed the Repository/Interface it looks like it is going to work.

Answer (score 1):

From your GET action method, you are passing a single object of `PatrolUnassignedViewModel`. But your view is bound to a collection of `PatrolUnassignedViewModel`. So change your view to be like

```
@model PatrolUnassignedViewModel
```

Now you can use the Model.Scout property which is a collection.

```
@model PatrolUnassignedViewModel
<h2>Total : @Model.Scout.Count()</h2>
@foreach(var item in Model.Scout)
{
   <label>@item.FirstName</label>
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about ? `Count` extension method is on IEnumerable<T> ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb338038(v=vs.100).aspx